# MariaDb: right syntax of PREPARE statement for CONNECT type tables when passing string variable

Tags: mariadb, prepared-statement

I run 10.4.12-MariaDB on Windows10 and I use 64-bit ODBC driver to connect tables from MS Access to MariaDB database. I am fighting with the right syntax of PREPARE statement for CONNECT type tables.

Having a table named fff which is ENGINE=CONNECT TABLE_TYPE=ODBC , I try to run prepared statements on it.
While I have **no trouble** to run statement with **integer type parameter**:

```
set @createStr = ("select * from fff where reltpfak = ? ");
prepare theSQL from @createStr ;
set @i = 1;
execute theSQL using @i;
-- works!
```

I can not find a right syntax to pass **string variable**. My trials lead to an **error**:

```
set @createStr = ("select reltpfak from fa where Firma = ? ;");
prepare theSQL from @createStr ;
set @i = "NameOfCompany";
execute theSQL using @i;
```

returns `Incorrect arguments to EXECUTE` .

The same one just with added ' around '?'

```
set @createStr = ("select reltpfak from fa where Firma = '?' ;")
prepare theSQL from @createStr ;
set @i = "NameOfCompany";
execute theSQL using @i
```

returns `Error: Got error 174 'SQLExecDirect: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Firma= NameOfCompany'.' from CONNECT` .

What is the right syntax of PREPARE statement for CONNECT type tables when passing string variable?

Comment: Please could you edit the question to include the full or at least the relevant parts of the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables `fff` and `fa`?

Comment: I did some typos: `fff` and `fa` are the same. Here it is:
`CREATE TABLE fff (ID INT(10) NOT NULL, ... PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=CONNECT `.
Details from information_schema:
`TABLE_TYPE='ODBC' TABNAME='Fa' DATA_CHARSET='cp1250' BLOCK_SIZE=10

Comment: ... and columns from queries are defined as:
`RelTpFak INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
Firma VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug as you can run this code just fine against an InnoDB table. It should work the same way against a Connect table, but apparently it doesn't. So I'd suggest you file a bug report in the [MariaDB Server Jira project](https://jira.mariadb.org/projects/MDEV/issues).